# Hide Chrome URL window from mobile

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio

How can I hide the taskbar of the Chrome browser on my mobile from Android Studio (URL, home button, windows, settings).
To make the web look like an app.

ANDROIDMANIFEST.java

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

ACTIVITY.java

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("pccomponentes.com")); 
    startActivity(intent);
```

If I use `WebView`, I get the problem that the camera does not work and I have no idea how to make it work. I have tried with permissions:

```
"android.permission.INTERNET"
"android.permission.CAMERA" 
"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
"android.webkit.PermissionRequest" 
"android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

Comment: You might want [WebView.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) Have a look at [this.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView)

Comment: You can move that bit of code to your question. You can edit the question if you want to add that bit of detail to it.

Comment: You can [edit] your question (see gray links under your question) instead of posting additional info in comments

Comment: I got it with WebView but then I have another problem that I've already asked (How to make the camera work on a web from webview in android studio?https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226059/como-hacer-que-la-c%C3%A1mara-funcione-en-una-web-desde-webview-en-android-studio).

I need or activate the camera from WebView when the web requires it or I do not see the top of Crhome.